# jQuery checkbox selection is not working in IE and is working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This is my selectall button code..on clicking this i am selecting all checkboxes..

```
   $('#PbtnSelectAll').click(function() {
        $('#PricingEditExceptions input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $('#PbtnSubmit').show();
            $('#PbtnCancel').show();
            $('fieldset').find("input:not(:checkbox),select,textarea").attr('disabled',true);
            $('#genericfieldset').find("input,select,textarea").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```

This code working in Firefox not in IE. Why it's doing like this?

Comment: btw: what (exactly) isn't working. the show(), the click event or the check box check attribute

Comment: I think it would be easier for people to lend you a helping hand if they also got to see the HTML.

Comment: Which versions of IE? Checkbox selection is working just fine for me in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/Xx5rE/

Comment: ok i will update with my HTML...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the id's of all your elements.  I'd be using .PbtnSelectAll etc and giving each element a class of the same.  At least the class doesn't change like the name can.

Comment: Would not make a difference, the its not the DOM that selects the elements its the Sizzle in jQ, if it works in firefox it should work in IE, the only thing thats manipulating the dom is the attr, wich may be the issues with the value of checked

Comment: i tried as RobertPitt and contagious sujjested but still no luck

Comment: @RobertPitt and how do you think Sizzle evaluates #id? It uses `document.getElementById()` - it is a sure recipe for problems to re-use element "id" values

Comment: @pointy,I know this, but what i was saying is that Sizzle traverse CSS/Attributed using Regex to create an identical system to CSS Selectors, my point was if `#someId[data-name*='rob']` works in FFX, it will also be found within IE,Chrome,Safari. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Well, I don't think that's actually always true, @RobertPitt. I think that the engine locates "id" references (#foo) and uses document.getElementById - therefore if there are multiple elements with the same "id" value, something weird can happen.

Comment: correct, witch is why i prefer to use a data-* attribute to hold meta data for that element, such as <a href="#" data-json="{....}"></a> and use that to traverse elements. what he needs to do is not use id's but classes,data-* attributes to select his elements.

Comment: OK, now we're in agreement :-)

Answer (score 0):

try using `"#Fieldset input:checkbox"` as your selector.

Comment: Have you experienced varying results when using `:checkbox` as opposed to `[type=checkbox]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean instead

`$('#Fieldset input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use true , false boolean. Can you try http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery ?

it's working in my IE 7.