# Checkbox issue with IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery chebox selection is not working in IE and is working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994538/jquery-chebox-selection-is-not-working-in-ie-and-is-working-in-firefox)

This is my new post regardence of prevoious post with update html code..

[jQuery chebox selection is not working in IE and is working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994538/jquery-chebox-selection-not-working-in-ie-this-is-working-in-firefox)

This is my selectall button code..on clicking this i am selecting all checkboxes..

This code working in Firefox not in IE can anybody help me out why its doing like this?

thanks

Comment: Please just edit the original question instead of posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `attr('disabled','disabled')` not `'disabled',true`

Comment: yes i did in both ways but no luck in IE6,..thanks

Comment: Setting it to `true` works fine, and always has in any browser I've ever tried it.